# I need a powershell script to Get Service Status along with a Particular display name and fields like Description Startup type

Tags: windows, powershell

I need a PowerShell script to Get Service Status along with a Particular display name and fields like Description Startup type.

`Get-Service -DisplayName Windows* | Filter Description,DisplayName, Status,Name`

[Example of the Service Details Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLEga.png)

Comment: Use following to get all properties.  Filter as needed :  Get-Service |  Select-object -Property *

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this script is helpful

```
$svcName = "SERVICENAME"
$svc = Get-Service $svcName

Write-Host "Name: " $svc.DisplayName
Write-Host "Status: " $svc.Status
Write-Host "Description: " $svc.Description
Write-Host "Start Type: " $svc.StartType
```

Comment: You're using the variable `$service` but you never define it. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
Get-Service -DisplayName Windows* | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Status, Name, Description
```

Comment: I need to send result via Email not as an attachment but in the Body



Get-Service -DisplayName Windows* |Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Status, Description| Out-File C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\Report\ServiceStatus.txt
Send-MailMessage -From ABC@Gmail.com -Subject "Services Status" -To XYZ@gmail.com -Attachments C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\Report\ServiceStatus.txt -Body "Donot Reply to this email" -DeliveryNotificationOption OnFailure,OnSuccess,Delay -Port 25 -Priority High -SmtpServer 11.19.17.78

Comment: @SV12VS, sorry for the delay. If you want to build a e-mail body, maybe it's better to add the results to a variable and then use it in the body. Something like that: "text $($var.displayname[0]) text $($var.Status[0]) etc etc"